# expected floating-point number but got ""

Tags: python

My program consists of creating an electricity bill. The values and variables I set to be appearing in the billing area are not appearing. And every time I click erase, I keep running into an error like: expected floating point number but got "". Another problem is that some of the bill is appearing under the frame and some are not even apparent at all. Could you please show me where the error lies?

```
    from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Facture d'électricité")
root.geometry('1300x800')

# Variables 
NCompt = IntVar()
Name = StringVar()
Adr = StringVar()
K = IntVar()


def total_bill():
    price = (0.098 * K.get())
    z = (K.get() - 1000)
    total = (z * 0.115 + prix)
    t = (total * 0.13)
    price2 = (t + total)
    totaltax = prix * 0.13
    tax = totaltax + K.get()
    lbl_rec = Text(C3, yscrollcommand=scrol_y)
    scrol_y.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    scrol_y.config(command=lbl_rec.yview)
    lbl_rec.pack()

    if (K.get() > 0 and K.get() <= 1000):
        price = 0.098 * K.get()
        totaltax = price * 0.13
        tax = totaltax + K.get()
    elif (K.get() > 1000):
        z = K.get() - 1000
        total = (z * 0.115) + price
        t = total * 0.13
        price2 = t + total
    else:
        lbl_rec.insert(END, "Electricity:")
        lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n======================================")
        lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n-Normal Tariff 1000 @ 0.098kWh/c :\t\t {price}")
        lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n-Additional Tariff +0.115c/kWh by every extra kWh:\t\t      {total}")
        lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n-T.V.H :\t\t      {t or tax}")
        lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n-Sub-Total :\t\t      {totaltax or price2}")
        lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n\n======================================")


def topRec():
    lbl_rec.delete(1.0, END)
    lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\t           Your bill of this month :")
    lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n Client name :\t\t{Name.get()}")
    lbl_rec.insert(END, f"\n Counter number:\t\t{NCompt.get()}")


def clear():
    Name.set('')
    NCompt.set('')
    Adr.set('')
    K.set('')
    topRecu()


# Program title
lblFacture_nom = Label(root, relief=GROOVE, justify=CENTER)
lblFacture_nom['text'] = 'Facture Mensuelle'
lblFacture_nom['font'] = 'Times 25 bold'
lblFacture_nom['bg'] = 'light grey'
lblFacture_nom['fg'] = 'white'
lblFacture_nom['bd'] = '12'
lblFacture_nom.pack(fill=X)


lblAnnonce = Label(root)
lblAnnonce['text'] = "Welcome to the program calculating electricity!"
lblAnnonce['font'] = 'Times 16'
lblAnnonce.place(x=350, y=60, anchor=NW)

lblEnoncé = Label(root)
lblEnoncé['text'] = 'Fill in with your informations:'
lblEnoncé['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lblEnoncé.place(x=30, y=140)

# Frame 1
lblC1 = LabelFrame(root, relief='groove', )
lblC1['text'] = 'Electricity'
lblC1['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lblC1['bg'] = 'light grey'
lblC1['fg'] = 'white'
lblC1['bd'] = '10'
lblC1.place(x=0, y=200, relwidth=1)

#Counter number
lbl_compteur = Label(lblC1)
lbl_compteur['text'] = 'Your counter number :'
lbl_compteur['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lbl_compteur['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_compteur['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_compteur.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

E_compteur = Entry(lblC1, width='15', textvariable=NCompt, relief='sunken', bd=5, )
E_compteur['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_compteur.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

# Frame 2
lblC2 = LabelFrame(root)
lblC2['text'] = 'Personal information :'
lblC2['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lblC2['bg'] = 'light grey'
lblC2['fg'] = 'white'
lblC2.place(x=20, y=300, width=630, height=500)

# Client name
lbl_nom = Label(lblC2)
lbl_nom['text'] = 'Your name:'
lbl_nom['font'] = 'Times 16 bold'
lbl_nom['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_nom['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_nom.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

E_nom = Entry(lblC2, width=20, textvariable=Name, relief='sunken', bd=5)
E_nom['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_nom.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# Adress entry
lbl_adr = Label(lblC2)
lbl_adr['text'] = 'Your adress :'
lbl_adr['font'] = 'Times 16 bold'
lbl_adr['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_adr['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_adr.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

E_adr = Entry(lblC2, width=20, textvariable=Adr, relief='sunken', bd=5)
E_adr['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_adr.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# Entry number of kilowatts used
lbl_kw = Label(lblC2)
lbl_kw['text'] = 'Number of kilowatts used :'
lbl_kw['font'] = 'Times 16 bold'
lbl_kw['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_kw['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_kw.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

E_kw = Entry(lblC2, width=20, textvariable=K, relief='sunken', bd=5)
E_kw['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_kw.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# Billing area
C3 = Frame(root, relief='groove', bd=10)
C3.place(x=700, y=300, width=500, height=500)

# Receipt title
lbl_trecu = Label(C3, bd=7, relief='groove')
lbl_trecu.pack(fill='x')
lbl_trecu['text'] = 'Bill receipt:'
lbl_trecu['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
# Scroll command
scrol_y = Scrollbar(C3, orient='vertical')

lbl_recu = Text(C3, yscrollcommand=scrol_y)
scrol_y.pack(side='right', fill='y')
scrol_y.config(command=lbl_recu.yview)
lbl_recu.pack()
topRec()

# Buttons
btn1 = Button(lblC2, text='Receipt', font='Times 13 bold', command=total_bill, padx=5, pady=10,
              bg='light blue', width=10)
btn1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=30)

btn2 = Button(lblC2, text='Erase', font='Times 13 bold', padx=5, pady=10, command=clear, bg='light blue', width=10)
btn2.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am trying your code on https://codehs.com/ and I got an error where I jumped over it by defining lbl_rec = Text() under your global variables to be accessed by all other functions!

Comment: What does command=total_facture for? Isn't supposed to call the total_bill function instead to process the receipt out?

Comment: I tried defining lbl_rec=Text() but when I do so the bill doesn't appear in my end. I will change the command now thank you.

Comment: It's still not printing the bill in the frame area :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some edits...

First, you got some typo in the code above, specifically in the total_bill() method please check!

Then, in total_bill() as well you got if elif and else....

You don’t need the last else since you need to print out the **Receipt** each time after the calculation

Now, if you notice that I moved the following line after we got the C3 definition and outside the function to be accessed globally in the program

```
lbl_recu = Text(C3, yscrollcommand=scrol_y)
```

Now, I recommend you prevent users from inserting empty data so that they don’t encounter bugs. you need to search for **data validation**

Please note also you would get a very long floating-point number which in my opinion is needed to be truncated. It depends on the meaning behind the floating-point numbers you could just surround them with int() or use sth like ceil() floor() or take a look at this
[https://datagy.io/python-truncate-float/#:~:text=Conclusion-,Use%20the%20int%20Function%20to%20Truncate%20a%20Float%20in%20Python,by%20removing%20its%20decimal%20places](https://datagy.io/python-truncate-float/#:%7E:text=Conclusion-,Use%20the%20int%20Function%20to%20Truncate%20a%20Float%20in%20Python,by%20removing%20its%20decimal%20places).

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Facture d'électricité")
root.geometry('1300x800')

# Variables 
NCompt = StringVar()
Name = StringVar()
Adr = StringVar()
K = IntVar()

def total_bill():
    price = (0.098 * K.get())
    z = (K.get() - 1000)
    total = (z * 0.115 + price)
    t = (total * 0.13)
    price2 = (t + total)
    totaltax = price2 * 0.13
    tax = totaltax + K.get()

    if (K.get() > 0 and K.get() <= 1000):
        price = 0.098 * K.get()
        totaltax = price * 0.13
        tax = totaltax + K.get()
    elif (K.get() > 1000):
        z = K.get() - 1000
        total = (z * 0.115) + price
        t = total * 0.13
        price2 = t + total
    
    topRec()
    lbl_recu.insert(END, "Electricity:")
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n======================================")
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n-Normal Tariff 1000 @ 0.098kWh/c :\t\t {price}")
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n-Additional Tariff +0.115c/kWh by every extra kWh:\t\t      {total}")
    lbl_recu.insert(END ,f"\n-T.V.H :\t\t      {t or tax}")
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n-Sub-Total :\t\t      {totaltax or price2}")
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n\n======================================")


def topRec():
    lbl_recu.delete(1.0, END)
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\t           Your bill of this month :")
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n Client name :\t\t{Name.get()}")
    lbl_recu.insert(END, f"\n Counter number:\t\t{NCompt.get()}\n")

def clear():
    Name.set('')
    NCompt.set('')
    Adr.set('')
    K.set('')
    lbl_recu.delete(1.0, END)

# Program title
lblFacture_nom = Label(root, relief=GROOVE, justify=CENTER)
lblFacture_nom['text'] = 'Facture Mensuelle'
lblFacture_nom['font'] = 'Times 25 bold'
lblFacture_nom['bg'] = 'light grey'
lblFacture_nom['fg'] = 'white'
lblFacture_nom['bd'] = '12'
lblFacture_nom.pack(fill=X)

lblAnnonce = Label(root)
lblAnnonce['text'] = "Welcome to the program calculating electricity!"
lblAnnonce['font'] = 'Times 16'
lblAnnonce.place(x=350, y=60, anchor=NW)

lblEnoncé = Label(root)
lblEnoncé['text'] = 'Fill in with your informations:'
lblEnoncé['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lblEnoncé.place(x=30, y=140)

# Frame 1
lblC1 = LabelFrame(root, relief='groove', )
lblC1['text'] = 'Electricity'
lblC1['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lblC1['bg'] = 'light grey'
lblC1['fg'] = 'white'
lblC1['bd'] = '10'
lblC1.place(x=0, y=200, relwidth=1)

#Counter number
lbl_compteur = Label(lblC1)
lbl_compteur['text'] = 'Your counter number :'
lbl_compteur['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lbl_compteur['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_compteur['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_compteur.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

E_compteur = Entry(lblC1, width='15', textvariable=NCompt, relief='sunken', bd=5, )
E_compteur['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_compteur.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)

# Frame 2
lblC2 = LabelFrame(root)
lblC2['text'] = 'Personal information :'
lblC2['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
lblC2['bg'] = 'light grey'
lblC2['fg'] = 'white'
lblC2.place(x=20, y=300, width=630, height=500)

# Client name
lbl_nom = Label(lblC2)
lbl_nom['text'] = 'Your name:'
lbl_nom['font'] = 'Times 16 bold'
lbl_nom['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_nom['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_nom.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

E_nom = Entry(lblC2, width=20, textvariable=Name, relief='sunken', bd=5)
E_nom['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_nom.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# Adress entry
lbl_adr = Label(lblC2)
lbl_adr['text'] = 'Your adress :'
lbl_adr['font'] = 'Times 16 bold'
lbl_adr['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_adr['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_adr.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

E_adr = Entry(lblC2, width=20, textvariable=Adr, relief='sunken', bd=5)
E_adr['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_adr.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# Entry number of kilowatts used
lbl_kw = Label(lblC2)
lbl_kw['text'] = 'Number of kilowatts used :'
lbl_kw['font'] = 'Times 16 bold'
lbl_kw['bg'] = 'light grey'
lbl_kw['fg'] = 'white'
lbl_kw.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=20)

E_kw = Entry(lblC2, width=20, textvariable=K, relief='sunken', bd=5)
E_kw['font'] = 'Times 14 bold'
E_kw.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

# Billing area
C3 = Frame(root, relief='groove', bd=10)
C3.place(x=700, y=300, width=500, height=500)

# Receipt title
lbl_trecu = Label(C3, bd=7, relief='groove')
lbl_trecu.pack(fill='x')
lbl_trecu['text'] = 'Bill receipt:'
lbl_trecu['font'] = 'Times 15 bold'
# Scroll command
scrol_y = Scrollbar(C3, orient='vertical')

lbl_recu = Text(C3, yscrollcommand=scrol_y)
scrol_y.pack(side='right', fill='y')
scrol_y.config(command=lbl_recu.yview)
lbl_recu.pack()

# Buttons
btn1 = Button(lblC2, text='Receipt', font='Times 13 bold', command=total_bill, padx=5, pady=10,
              bg='light blue', width=10)
btn1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=30)

btn2 = Button(lblC2, text='Erase', font='Times 13 bold', padx=5, pady=10, command=clear, bg='light blue', width=10)
btn2.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It runs perfectly but the only downside is that it still prints at the very end of the receipt and not the top. Is there a way to print the results at the top of the receipt? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I will try to do that but please try again right now since I changed 
NCompt = IntVar() to StringVar() because it was giving the same error in topRec() in the insert method!

Comment: Is there a way to use lbl['text'] instead of using the text widget  like (text.insert END) when doing the billing area ? I think it's the one causing issues and I am a beginner so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you Mohamad for all your help, I just need your help with the showing of the bill in the billing area and I will be happy to upvote your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Danny
I have done that for you. If you feel you need to understand sth let me know so I can explain. 
Don’t forget to upvote it. Thanks!